# Power BI YouTube integration

Tags: youtube-data-api, powerbi-datasource

I'm trying to get comments from my YouTube channel using Power BI.

I've wrote some code and got the list of YouTube videos. Now I need to get the comments of all of those videos; however, I can't because I have an error:

`DataSource.Error: Web.Contents не удалось получить содержимое из "https://youtube.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/commentThreads?part=id,snippet,replies%2Creplies&videoId=huFoOWhPoZ8,UA96g-ylWHs,x4S8cWsXKt8,4xZ04pu2b6U,o7gnn1X1H6g,KthLk1o7fg8,h9QUHWjSa1o,QNhjxjvw2Nw,G2ReHG8vB8U,QZU8P71UsAc,rt_GJIu8faU,mYxC7gd0wNw,5zJFb_KE9iY,l1EwQn_0hyY,1x3pWU4GMQw,U_reMZNvjes,b1PfyEK-D8E,O6GPZKY3tQ0,BT_ugE7sCI4,QkGqsSjykGY,A5Oyo0jlLeM,B24qvAaP08g,oGPbs3n5dCI,N7HxP0mDYrA,utHwM-rfG5A,9OW3sB5eE4c,9BPyGYhEAY8,sdiuko9lgDA,10gRqJDMe6o,HLWBFawvk9o,KVFrMJ4KtP8,ooc_2wELgr0,BUleWDhr59Q,1NcbQWYdDos,xW3amsV6ejE,mBByB-5_2Lo,HE-V5vBh5M0,PNsO0_dT1w0,pI2eou7heMA,Xjh1vPwHesI,PI-hoIFXj7c,1Ga1h7clb1Q,qpCAeO1Rj48,uI6IarRjkpA,2OEVzqRoMU0,0bc46IuPKP0,Ot6-vyji2DY,Pr88fTzX1Hc,d1uDA1XqJK4,hbsvXcap28A&maxResults=100&moderationStatus=published&pageToken=&textFormat=plainText&key=..." (404): Not Found`

The code is the following:

```
let 

    Source = Json.Document(Web.Contents("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&channelId=" & ChannelId & "&key=" & APIKey & "&type=video&maxResults=" & #"Max Results" )),
    items = Source[items],
    #"Converted to Table" = Table.FromList(items, Splitter.SplitByNothing(), null, null, ExtraValues.Error),
    #"Expanded Column1" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Converted to Table", "Column1", {"id", "snippet"}, {"id", "snippet"}),
    #"Expanded id" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Expanded Column1", "id", {"videoId"}, {"videoId"}),
    #"Expanded Column1.snippet" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Expanded id", "snippet", {"publishedAt", "title", "description"}, {"publishedAt", "title", "description"}),
    videoId = #"Expanded Column1.snippet"[videoId],
    videostring = Text.RemoveRange(List.Accumulate(videoId, "", (state,current) => state & "," & current),0,1),

    Stats = Json.Document(Web.Contents("https://youtube.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/commentThreads?part=id,snippet,replies%2Creplies&videoId= " & videostring & "&maxResults=100&moderationStatus=published&pageToken=&textFormat=plainText&key= " &APIKey& ""))

in 
   Stats
```

Comment: You have passed on to the request parameter `videoId` a comma-separated list of 48 video IDs; but, as per the official specification of [`videoId`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/commentThreads/list#videoId), the `CommentThreads.list` API endpoint does not accept that. Your `videoId` parameter has to be set to one and only one video ID.

Comment: Thank you! perhaps you know another way to get the comments?

Comment: For getting the top-level comments of a given set of videos -- identified by their respective IDs -- there's no other way than iterating over each ID in the given set of video IDs for to call separately `CommentThreads.list` queried with `videoId` set to one video ID.

Comment: is there any way to do it automatically or i need to iterate each videoId by myself?

Comment: Iterate over each ID, as I already said.